General OAuth architecture query - using social login for your app/web's RESTful service
I'm trying to understand the correct flow - given this common scenario:

HelloWorld Mobile App or Web
Connects to it's RESTful services on HelloWorld.com
Needing to authenticate to use the RESTful services using username/password or social logins (Google/Facebook etc)

What is the correct flow here?  Is it

HelloWorldApp directly calls GoogleAuth service directly, gets the token, and somehow lets HelloWorld.com know to use that for authentication?
HelloWorldApp calls HelloWorld.com which makes the call to GoogleAuth, the callback to HelloWorld.com allows it to store the token, and passes back to HelloWorldApp?


Your question is flagged with OAuth2, so I'll answer with OAuth2 and OpenID in mind.
User authentication is done by the authorization server - aka OpenID Provider or OP in OpenID spec - and neither by Spring applications configured with oauth2Login nor those with oauth2ResourceServer. About any OpenID Provider offers a variety of login flows: username/password with & without multifactor authentication (OneTimePassword with authenticator app, email, text message, etc.), social login, magic link, remember-me cookie, etc.
Google login is performed by Google's authorization server. The access tokens it emits have Google API as audience, meaning that it should not be used to authorize requests to your resource servers. The ID tokens it emits have as audience whatever you have defined as OAuth2 client in Google's UI (it's the same for any other social identity provider). You might use these ID tokens in a Spring application with oauth2Login, but as I already wrote in my answer to this other question of yours, it is of interest only in simplistic scenarios, and it is most frequently preferable to have your own authorization server in front of social identity providers.
As explained in the 2nd section of this article I wrote, your option 1. is now discouraged for security reasons. As you seem not to trust me enough to read that article, read this post from Spring Security team.
So, you need to:

spin an authorization server for your system. I wrote a tutorial for getting started with Keycloak & Spring
learn about the OAuth2 BFF pattern
learn to ask more specific questions and read the answers (including the linked content) before asking new ones on the same subject.


(This post was meant to try and be more general, the other being a bit more of a specific scenario, but I appreciate your responses).  I have setup a test keycloak/springboot and have basic authentication (via postman), but I'm still trying to figure out how the mobile app is supposed to authenticate via a social provider and get back a session id from BE.
I think it should be:  MobileApp calls GoogleAuth directly -> App sends credential to Keycloak when in callback -> App then (somehow) logs into springboot which authenticates against keycloak -> BE sends session back to mobile app.

Similar to https://nikhilsomansahu.medium.com/how-to-implement-google-sign-in-feature-in-flutter-app-71d957cac39b, but it sends cred to Firebase only.

No. One of the points of OAuth2 is that only the authorization server should collect credentials. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/79091223/619830 (already linked in the answer to your other question)

As far as I can tell both options are valid and come with different pros and cons.
Option 1: Client obtains token from Auth server
This solution is, for example, recommended when using the Auth0 SDK for React or when using the Google Sign In button.
Option 2: Client calls backend, backend obtains token from Auth server
This solution is known as Backend For Frontend (BFF) and is described in this tutorial from Auth0 and in this draft specification.
Option 1 might be preferable if you are looking for a "simple login solution" and want to use the token for authentication against your own backend.
I have encountered option 2 in a web application that already used a session cookie for authentication, and we wanted to extend it with social login. In this case, we obtained the token from the Auth server in the redirect callback to the backend, set the session cookie, and then redirected back to the web application.
If you want to extend your question with more details about your use case, I can provide more concrete help.

There is a difference between using the tokens issued by Google (option 1. in the question) or issued by Auth0 after "login with Google" - and you shouldn't use Google's access token to authorize requests to your resource servers. Also, I don't agree with a highlighted statement about the BFF article you link: "This pattern does not work for a pure SPA". Well, I have a few "pure SPAs" that use this pattern.

Last, risks of public clients go beyond issuing tokens to a client without a secret. When sending tokens to the frontend, you expose it to dependencies code (XSS attacks) and potentially to unsafe storage (that depends on the OAuth2 client lib used in the frontend and on its configuration). Sending JWTs to frontend also breaks the ability to instantly revoke user access (you can't invalidate a JWT and have to wait until it expires).
